# Continuous rebase of a git branch from master results in duplicate commits

Tags: git, synchronization, branch, rebase

I have a release branch which is branched off from master.
And there will be some local commits on the release branch.
I need to keep syncing the release branch from master. So I run a script every morning with the following steps:

1. `git checkout releasebranch`
2. `git rebase -Xtheirs master` (Xtheirs so that local changes on release branch overrides in case of conflicts )
3. `git pull origin releasebranch --rebase` (to keep my local commits in place after rebase)
4. `git push origin releasebranch`

This is causing duplicated commits and there are lot of diff from master branch.
Any clue whether I'm following the right method to sync a branch?

**Note**:
 a. I need to run an automated script to sync so resolving conflicts manually is not practical. That's why used `Xtheirs` option.
b. Tried `git merge -Xours master`  and it is throwing hell lot of conflicts.
c. I have another branch which is syncing from master with `git rebase -s ours master` command, and it is working fine. But in this case I need local changes on releasebranch to override the changes in master.

Answer (score 2):

Your third and fourth steps look suspicious to me.  Ideally, if you're using a rebase workflow for `releasebranch`, you would be the only one using that branch.  So the second step makes sense, because that is how you keep up to date with `master`.  But I'm not sure about synching up with other changes coming from people sharing this branch.

For your fourth step, since you may have rewritten the history of the `releasebranch`, the following would fail most of the time:

```
git push origin releasebranch
```

Instead, you would need to *force* push the release branch via:

```
git push --force origin releasebranch
```

So may advice is to possibly eliminate step 3 if you can, and then to force push in the fourth step.